# ArcGIS linefeed character for Identify window using SQL View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, identify

I've searched everywhere but have been unable to find the solution. Using a view from SQL I have a semicolon separated field that when I info each feature I want to have a line break in the results window for each semicolon basically. I have seen it done before but am unable to find the character that I can feed through the view that Arc's identify tool respects.

SQL - SSMS 17.8.1
ARC - 10.5